# Types,realizing,conjunction

Tags: logic

Define for types (finitely satisfiable maximal sets of formulas with parameters in some model $\mathcal M$) $p,q$ :

> $p \vDash q$

when every sequence realizing p realizes q.

Why it suffices to test that for every **FINITE** $q' \subseteq q$ there is a finite $p' \subseteq p$ such that $p' \vDash q'$ ?

Comment: Hint: The Compactness Theorem